# How do I find the Azure PowerShell version?

Tags: powershell, azure, version, powershell-cmdlet, azure-powershell

I need to find the installed Azure PowerShell version through cmdlets code. How do I find the Azure PowerShell version?

Note: Other than cmdlets code is also welcome.

Comment: does my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: here is the latest one: `Get-Module AzureRM -ListAvailable | Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Path`

Comment: I tried every other command listed in answer in this post, but none of these works so I just downloaded and installed the latest version using [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps-msi) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596190/1176573). :(

Comment: Wish there was `Get-AzPwshVersion` !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
(Get-Module azure).Version
```

This will return version of installed Azure PowerShell.

[image: Azure PowerShell version]

Comment: This solution will not work if the Azure module has not been loaded into the current PowerShell session. It will just return empty, tested on my environment. It only works when I have called any cmdlet from the Azure module in the current PowerShell session.

Comment: For me that's what worked: `(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh).Version`

Comment: See the answer by Jonathan-Gao that uses the Get-InstalledModule command

Answer (score 52):

This PowerShell cmdlet will get the Azure PowerShell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

It has a major advantage in which it will be able to return the expected outcome even if the Azure module has not been loaded into the current PowerShell session.

On the contrary, `(Get-Module Azure).Version` will only work if the Azure module has been loaded into the current PowerShell session before, i.e. by calling any cmdlet from the Azure module in the current PowerShell session, e.g. `Get-AzureStorageAccount`

[image]

Comment: `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` is not listing Version and Name columns.Am i missing anything else?

Comment: Hi @ManirajSS, I retry exactly the same command and is able to get the expected result as shown in my answer. May I know what powershell version and platform you're running on? My current Azure PowerShell version is 1.0.4.

Comment: @juvchan When I run your cmdlet in Windows Powershell it returns your output, but when I run it in Microsoft Azure Powershell it returns `ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Manifest   Azure                     {New-AzureServiceRemoteDesktopExtensionConfig, New-AzureStorageContext,  ... `, without Version /cc @ManirajSS

Comment: The output of this command depends upon the version of powershell you are using.  The output in the answer is from powershell 5.0, whereas the output in @FrankvanEykelen comment is from powershell 3.0.  Use $PSVersionTable.PSVersion to check your powershell version

Answer (score 16):

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az -AllVersions | select Name,Version
```

It is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following cmdlet to get the Azure PowerShell version as well!

Copy and paste the following, and run it!

```
(Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq 'Azure' }) ` | Select Version, Name, Author, PowerShellVersion  | Format-List;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-Module AzureRM -List | Select-Object Name, Version, Path
```

This is great to run if you have multiple versions running.

Answer (score 3):

Use official : 
[$PSVersionTable.PSVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-5.6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-3.6.1)

Comment: For me, this command just gives me the powershell version without any reference to AzureAd.  For me, I'm using azure online, so I can get the info with this command: `Get-Module Azuread -ListAvailable | Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Path`

Answer (score 1):

It runs in AzureServiceManagementMode and not in ARM mode in version 0.8 and 0.9.
It works smooth with the version 1.0 and above.

```
 $name='Azure' 

    if(Get-Module -ListAvailable |  Where-Object { $_.name -eq $name })  
    {  
      (Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq $name }) |  Select Version, Name, Author, PowerShellVersion  | Format-List;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        “The Azure PowerShell module is not installed.” 
    }
```

[image]

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command in PowerShell gives me the current Azure PowerShell version.

`Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Az`