# Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount thorws error Could not load file or assembly

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am using win2k12 R2 standard 62 bit version OS and i am trying to automate deployment of my api services and web application to azure using azure arm command-lets in power-shell
i am able to run the command Login-AzureRmAccount and Set-AzureSubscription
But 
When i try to run the command Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount i am getting below error "Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation"

The same command works correctly in windows 10 64 bit version OS.

Comment: can you compare versions of azure powershell between the computers as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157067/how-to-find-azure-powershell-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem in a recently released version of the SDK. [It has since been hotfixed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2747). (as in a few hours ago from the time of this post). If you use the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and update Microsoft Azure Powershell, you should be good to go.